# Flutter How to translate text snippet that comes from backend (api) (i.e. translation as key)

Tags: laravel, flutter, localization, translation

I guess, I just wanted to confirm that flutter doesn't support translation string as key. I have followed "[Introduction to localizations in Flutter](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization#introduction-to-localizations-in-flutter)" tutorial and checked out packages like "[Easy Localization](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization)".

Defining a key for a string in **every language** is a pain, time consuming and impossible to translate strings that comes from backend api. What I want to achieved is [something that is possible in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/localization#using-translation-strings-as-keys). Is that possible in Flutter yet?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: hey!, so get the best of easy_localizations, you can check out lokalise which my team uses(its paid though) doing this you wont need any translation files. my team currently uses this and it scales really well

Comment: Not familiar with Laravel but I've created my own mechanism for Translation (not released as a package yet) while ditching the Easy Localization package (which wasn't even realtime). So, to understand your question better, What I've understood is you want to use the Key or the value based on the language, so, if it's English use the key, if it's Spanish, use the value, utilizing only a single json file?

Comment: @MAfzal thank you for your suggestion but I am not into paid software at the moment.

Comment: @LalitFauzdar Yes exactly! Let's say I have the translation json file with `{ "Hello": "Hola" }`. 

In Laravel, I only have to display the English text `{{ __('Hello') }}`. Laravel handle to replace that with "Hola" when user switch the language which is really intuitive, I think.